# что передавать в value в cookie?

Tags: веб-программирование, cookie

дайте пожалуйста внятный ответ. Я пока работу так представляю, создаётся в таблице поле хеша login + password + текущее время. и это передается в value для cookie. потом когда надо сравнить cookie, ищется в базе данные в этой таблице и если есть, то разрешается доступ. так?

Comment: Ни в коем случае! Кука для аутентификации должна быть полностью случайной.

Comment: @andreymal и как тогда делать?